# Error in xml layout:The following classes could not be found: - android.support.v4.view.Viewpager

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, sdk

My **android.support.v4.jar** is in my libs folder and in my android private libraries also.

But I got a problem appearing over top of my my xml layout saying- "The following classes could not be found: - android.support.v4.view.Viewpager."

I'm not sure whats wrong please help! I've searched around many forums and nothing seems to be working. The same problem occured when I tried integrating admod into my application it said, on the xml layout, The following classes could not be found: - android.support.v4.ads.AdRequest. I have a hunch it has to do with my jar being in the wrong spot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference your project with this library.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What library? and what do you suppose I do to fix it?

Comment: android.support.v4.jar library

Comment: @user2648999 which IDE you are using?

Comment: Eclipse, ADT, android 4.3

Comment: @ErrorMaster I believe it is: Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libs > Add Internal > select  android.support.v4.jar > click many oks

Comment: When i get to java build path there is no libs folder under any of the tabs named -source -project -libraries -order and export, also no option to add internal only add external JAR :(

Comment: @ErrorMaster Project Properties > Libraries > Add JARs... > your libs folder > android.support.v4.jar > OK > OK

Comment: Project Properties> Libraries - JARs and class folders on build path: android.support.v4.jar - [project_name]/libs and there are couple other folders under it, is this what its supposed to look like? It is still giving me the error.

Comment: @ErrorMaster what kind of error? are you able to import `Viewpager` ?

Comment: I am able to import with no problems ( import android.view.View ) how ever the error appears over top of my xml layout, it seems to be a build error of sorts im not sure - because my reputation is not high enough i cant post pictures - heres a link to my screen shot, i think this might help http://i.imgur.com/OtJwCcH.png

Comment: @ErrorMaster can you try to reference it in code? `Viewpager vp = new Viewpager(this);`

Comment: Thanks for all your help btw, really appricated, i put that line right after the onCreate method and it says the varible vp is unused, what else needs to go where?

Comment: @ErrorMaster so it does not say that it cannot find `Viewpager` ? This means that the library is imported and is part of the project now. Show how you are trying to add `Viewpager` in your `XML` file

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/WDseLkr.png this is my xml file where im trying to add the viewpager

Comment: @ErrorMaster have you tried to compile/build your application?

Comment: @ErrorMaster and it is `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` not `android.support.v4.view.Viewpager`

Comment: The capitalization got rid of the error on the xml file, thank you very much - but one more question do you know why the layout looks blank? its not displaying the swipey tabs it should, if you dont i understand just wondering

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/PRzqEvw.png - xml file layout that should have a couple different swipey tabs

Comment: @ErrorMaster it is because designer does not show custom views imported in such a way (at least this is what I have experienced over the time)

Comment: do you know a way in which the designer will show the costom views imported??

Answer (score 2):

hey i've fixed this by converting the ViewPager 
from "android.support.v4.view.Viewpager" to "androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager".

to do that you just have to open up the .xml file > design and then right click on that ViewPager > Convert view as shown the next picture

[image]

then you just type viewPager and the search bar will auto complete that.. thats all of it.

[image]

Hope this fix the issue like it did to me.

Comment: Helped a lot! Applied the logic to all my old support views and converted them to AndroidX views. Took a while, but worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the SDK Manager.
- Create a libs/ directory in the root of your application project.
- Copy the JAR file from your Android SDK installation directory (e.g., /extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar) into your application's project libs/ directory.
- Right click the JAR file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html